# Column which contain for each row the count of a specific value in the whole dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column which will contain for each row the count of a specific value in the whole dataset.

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [2,3,4,5,6], 'c':['or','ta','fl','or','fl'], 'd':[5,9,1,3,7]})
```

I would like to add a column `e` which count for each row how many times the value of column `c` appear in the dataset, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [2,3,4,5,6], 'c':['or','ta','fl','or','fl'], 'd':[5,9,1,3,7], 'e':[2,1,2,2,2]})

   a  b   c  d  
0  1  2  or  5  
1  2  3  ta  9  
2  3  4  fl  1  
3  4  5  or  3  
4  5  6  fl  7
```

I tried to iterate over the whole dataset but it didnt work:

```
def getSum(c):
return df[df==c].sum()

def createE(df):
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['e'] = getSum(row['c'])

return df


   a  b   c  d  e
0  1  2  or  5  2
1  2  3  ta  9  1
2  3  4  fl  1  2
3  4  5  or  3  2
4  5  6  fl  7  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) for this, and use the `'count'` for parameter of `transform`:

```
df['e']=df.groupby('c')['c'].transform('count')
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
   a  b   c  d  e
0  1  2  or  5  2
1  2  3  ta  9  1
2  3  4  fl  1  2
3  4  5  or  3  2
4  5  6  fl  7  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map each value in the column c to its count.

Setup

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [2,3,4,5,6], 'c':['or','ta','fl','or','fl'], 'd':[5,9,1,3,7]})           
>>> df                                                                                                                 
   a  b   c  d
0  1  2  or  5
1  2  3  ta  9
2  3  4  fl  1
3  4  5  or  3
4  5  6  fl  7
```

Solution

```
>>> df['e'] = df.c.map(df.c.value_counts())                                                                            
>>> df                                                                                                                 
   a  b   c  d  e
0  1  2  or  5  2
1  2  3  ta  9  1
2  3  4  fl  1  2
3  4  5  or  3  2
4  5  6  fl  7  2
```